# How to send message when file changes detected? Twisted and Web Sockets

Tags: python, windows, web-services, sockets, twisted

I am currently trying to create a small demo where I connect a web socket between my computer and my localhost `ws://localhost:8080/ws`. I want the web socket to monitor a file on my computer for changes. If there are changes, send a message. The connection and output is being monitored using Advanced Rest Client.

Is there a specific method I can use on the class to constantly check the contents of this file?

## EDIT

I have implemented an observer using `watchdog` that detects any event for files in a specified directory. However, my message is not being sent in the `sendFSEvent` method and I also realized that my client isn't being registered when I connect to the web socket.

Here is my code in `server.py`

```
import sys
import os

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, \
    WebSocketServerProtocol, listenWS

from MessangerEventHandler import MessangerEventHandler


class WsProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print("Connection made")
        WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionMade(self)

    def onOpen(self):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.onOpen(self)
        print("WebSocket connection open")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("Message was: {}".format(payload))
        self.sendMessage("message received")

    def sendFSEvent(self, json):
        WebSocketProtocol.sendMessage(self, json)
        print('Sent FS event')

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("Connection closed: {}".format(reason))
        WebSocketServerProtocol.onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason)


class WsServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
    protocol = WsProtocol

    def __init__(self, url='ws://localhost', port=8080):
        addr = url + ':' + str(port)
        print("Listening on: {}".format(addr))
        WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, addr)
        self.clients = []

    def register(self, client):
        if not client in self.clients:
            print("Registered client: {}".format(client))
            self.clients.append(client)

    def unregister(self, client):
        if client in self.clients:
            print("Unregistered client: {}".format(client))
            self.clients.remove(client)
        self._printConnected()

    def _printConnected(self):
        print("Connected clients:[")

    def notify_clients(self, message):
        print("Broadcasting: {}".format(message))
        for c in self.clients:
            c.sendFSEvent(message)
        print("\nSent messages")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python server_defer.py <dirs>")
        sys.exit(1)

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    ffactory = WsServerFactory("ws://localhost", 8080)
    ffactory.protocol = WsProtocol
    listenWS(ffactory)

    observers = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        dir_path = os.path.abspath(arg)
        if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
            print('{} does not exist.'.format(dir_path))
            sys.exit(1)
        if not os.path.isdir(dir_path):
            print('{} is not a directory.'.format(dir_path))
            sys.exit(1)

        # Check for and handle events
        event_handler = MessangerEventHandler(ffactory, reactor, os.getcwd())

        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=dir_path, recursive=True)
        observer.start()

        observers.append(observer)

    try:
        reactor.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for obs in observers:
            obs.stop()
        reactor.stop()
        print("\nGoodbye")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: what OS will you be running this app in?

Comment: Windows right now, but will switch to Linux (Red Hat).

Comment: In *nix, there's the `mtime` attribute of a file (cf. `os.path.getmtime(path)`) which you could check periodically. Another option is to calculate a checksum for the file, and act when it is changed.

Comment: For Linux, you can use Twisted's `inotify` options. As for Windows...I have yet to meet anyone that found a long term solution that they're satisfied with.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added an edit to my original post with code that is detecting file changes, but not sending a message to the socket connection. I am going to switch over to Linux and see if I can get this message notification working with `inotify` if this isn't resolved soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most enterprise distros come with `inotify` which is really well suited for monitoring files and directories. The basic idea is to capture a list of connected web socket clients as they connect. Then create a callback that will execute when a change occurs on the files you're monitoring. Within this callback, you can iterate the clients and send them a message like `'file: "blah/blah.txt" has changed'`. It's a little wonky, but the code snippet should clear things up for you.

```
from functools import partial
from twisted.internet import inotify
from twisted.python import filepath
# the rest of your imports ...


class SomeServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, request):
        self.factory.append(self)       # <== append this client to the list in the factory


def notification_callback(ignored, filepath, mask, ws_clients):
    """
    function that will execute when files are modified
    """
    payload = "event on {0}".format(filepath)
    for client in ws_clients:
        client.sendMessage(
            payload.encode('utf8'),    # <== don't forget to encode the str to bytes before sending!
            isBinary = False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = File(".")
    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.01:8080")
    factory.protocol = SomeServerProtocol
    factory.clients = []        # <== create a container for the clients that connect

    # inotify stuff
    notify = partial(notification_callback, ws_clients=factory.clients)   # <== use functools.partial to pass extra params
    notifier = inotify.INotify()
    notifier.startReading()
    notifier.watch(filepath.FilePath("/some/directory"), callbacks=[notify])

    # the rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an `INotifyError: Failed to add watch on ''/home/bweber/pub_sub_example/test_files''`. My code is written as `notifier.watch(filepath.FilePath("test_files"), callbacks=[notify]). Any idea on why I am getting this error?

Comment: Never mind. Just realized that folder is on my windows machine and I switched over to the Linux one now. Oh my...